# Why is there an "End Transmission" message after long range communication?

Tags: star-trek

Why after finishing any distant Federation communication, there is an "End Transmission" text:

[image]

Shouldn't it be:

- Transmission's End,
- End of Transmission,
- Transmission has Ended or
- *something different*

"End Transmission" sound much more like a order or command ("*End transmission now!*"), not like an informational message.

(*assuming, this question is on-topic and shouldn't be asked on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/)*)

Comment: The computer is ordering Picard to disconnect the call. All UFP vessels are constructed by Skynet.

Comment: This question is certainly on topic here. Off the top of my head, perhaps the screen is the last message from the sender, not the computers generated "The transmission has been terminated" message.

Comment: Ugghh, there was another question somewhere on here about something similar, and I think Thaddeus answered it from a real-life perspective.  Articles are dropped for terseness/simplicity when the meaning isn't changed.  So it's a shortened form of your suggested "End of Transmission".

Comment: My first instinct, when I saw this question, was to downvote it to oblivion. Then I realised it's a damn good and fair question. _However_.... not one to which I expect you to ever get an answer. So its value here is questionable!

Answer (score 4):

From the looks of the image, I'd say the textbox they use to display that message only has room for *x* characters until it spreads the text across multiple lines.

You have to admit;

> End of
>
> Transmission

just doesn't look very professional.

Comment: i think they could fit an extra two characters and two more spaces without a line break, especially with kerning.

Comment: It may look spacious enough, but it really is dependent on the textbox and fontsize.  I've seen texts that should have fit without issue be ix-nayed because one of their pixels was a rebel and went overboard.  We live in a harsh world.

Comment: Naaah, I think, they'd rather pick a smaller font than make so obvious mistake (?). I think, I must disagree with you, so only +1, but no acceptance.

Answer (score 3):

In cabled transmissions (e.g., telegraphs or telex) the operator inserted "ENDS" or an end-of-transmission character to indicate the end of the message. Newspapers used to insert the number "30" to indicate end of the article. Many press releases still insert "ENDS" at the bottom of the release. This lets the reader know there aren't any missing pages or paragraphs. I would say its to let the recipient know the transmission is over, instead of being lost etc. Everything that needed saying has been said and that screen is just a variation on that theme.

Answer (score 1):

I always took this to actually be an instruction! telling the user to hang up, like the dial tone when on a landline when the other person hangs up (In the time it was made this makes sense: hear tone meant put the phone down as the other person has hung up).

Or maybe in deep space, considering that most messages aren't 2 way: you hang up to acknowledge receipt of the transmission so the relay station doesn't have to keep sending it. It could be as simple as marking an email as read (by ending) or leaving unread (by hitting cancel)

This is pure speculation but I always saw that message as an instruction to hang up and clear the line: which is how most landlines worked back then - if you don't hang up then no-one can call you till you do (or send you another message in this context)

It make sense with long range communications: if you received the message in tack then 'end transmission' (confirm), else 'send another copy' (cancel: or something). It is asking have you received the message intact AND its not been scrambled in transit --- maybe a question-mark at the end is missing but i think it is a question